# How to Find Generated Column Definition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, information-schema

I have added a virtual generated column to the salaries table in the test employees database as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE salaries
    ADD COLUMN salary_k int AS (salary / 1000);
```

Now when I query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` the `EXTRA` column shows `VIRTUAL GENERATED` as expected, but how can I get the details of the generated column, i.e. in this case `(salary / 1000)`?  `COLUMN_DEFAULT` shows `NULL`.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE salaries` shows the details in the result, but I want the result as part of a larger query of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, so that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Incidentally, by defining salary_k as an int, in the event that salary is not an even thousand, you will have interesting behavior.

Comment: This was just a test to see how I can find the definition.  I have no use for the `salary_k` column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in the `GENERATION_EXPRESSION` column of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html):

> `GENERATION_EXPRESSION`
>   For generated columns, displays the expression used to compute column values.

Comment: this does ` GENERATION_EXPRESSION` is not found in MySQL 5.5, what is the alternative

Comment: Virtual columns were added in 5.7. It doesn't make sense to try to look up something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more practical answer:

```
SELECT column_name, generation_expression
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'salaries'
```